# How to Display Different images on each face of cube in opengl (android)?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, 3d, cube

I am making a 3D cube, I can assign one image for every face, but I would like to assign different images for each face.I used the NeHe Port for reference, so for one image the function is::

```
 public static Bitmap getTextureFromBitmapResource(Context context, int resourceId)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try
    {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), yFlipMatrix, false);
    } finally
    {
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function in my Renderer like this::

```
Bitmap texture = getTextureFromBitmapResource(context, R.drawable.img1);
```

But i can set only one image to every face. I want to set different images for each face. I tried making an array of images and then passing it to this function but in vain.

Answer (score 3):

[Texture arrays](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt) (if it is what you are referring to) should work, but it depends on the way you calculate the layer in your shader.

Otherwise, you must either draw each face individually and bind the right texture each time, or use a [cubemap](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_cube_map.txt).